# How to import CSV file with many column names to sqlite database in android programatically

Tags: android, sqlite, csv

I have a CSV files with 100s of Column names, I want to import this file as a new table in my existing Sqlite database such that First row makes Column names and from second row values to the columns. How can I do this in android programatically. Any help will be appreciable

Comment: have you looked at any resources online? have you tried anything so far?

Comment: yes but i was not able to implement loop for 100s of column names

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to insert large amount of data in sqlite database in Android](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31668405/how-to-insert-large-amount-of-data-in-sqlite-database-in-android)